# Ag-grid - read all data in master / detail

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

For Ag grid Master/Detail, is there a way to get all of the data e.g. detail grid cell value is changed and on that change want to get all of the data including master rows and details rows?

Answer (score 0):

listen to `onCellValueChanged` event on detail grid and then call a global function that reads the master grid data.

```
detailGridOptions: {
  columnDefs: [
    { field: 'callId' },
    { field: 'direction', minWidth: 150, editable: true },
    { field: 'number' },
    { field: 'duration', valueFormatter: "x.toLocaleString() + 's'" },
    { field: 'switchCode', minWidth: 150 },
  ],
  onCellValueChanged: (params)=> {
    let rowData = [];
    params.api.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
    console.log('detail grid data',rowData)
    console.log('master grid data', this.getMasterGridData())
  },
  defaultColDef: {
    flex: 1,
  },
},
```

and on the parent compenent you have:

```
  getMasterGridData() {
    let rowData = [];
    this.masterGridApi.forEachNode(node => rowData.push(node.data));
    return rowData
  }
```

here's a complete [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EEaXsR5IvteEfiEF?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts) (try to edit the direction column on detail grid)